# MYSQL statement not showing me the correct vaules

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to the MySQL/PHP field, learning on my own. I am trying to pull data on items shipped, here is the Query I am using:-

```
select jobs.job_number, jobs.employee_end, jobs.qty_comp, jobs.`date`,SUM(jobs.scrap), SUM(jobs.job_time) 
FROM jobs where jobs.job_number in (
SELECT j.job_number FROM jobs j
 WHERE j.moved_to = 'shipped'
   AND j.`date` BETWEEN '2016-11-28' AND '2016-12-02'
   AND j.qty_comp > 0
)
GROUP BY jobs.job_number
```

I receive the correct `SUM(scrap)` and `SUM(job_time)` and `job_numbers`, its not showing me the last entry with `moved_to = 'shipped', qty_comp > 0`. It shows the first entry of the first scan of the `job_number`.

Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query can be rewritten as (without the need for a subquery):

```
SELECT jobs.job_number, jobs.employee_end, jobs.qty_comp, jobs.`date`,
SUM(jobs.scrap), SUM(jobs.job_time)
FROM jobs AS j
WHERE j.moved_to = 'shipped' AND 
j.`date` BETWEEN '2016-11-28' AND '2016-12-02' AND
j.qty_comp > 0
GROUP BY jobs.job_number
```

The "IN" condition is not necessary and since the aggregation (group by) is by job_number only jobs.job_number, SUM(jobs.scrap), SUM(jobs.job_time) will have meaningful values.

Since columns jobs.employee_end, jobs.qty_comp, jobs.`date` will come from multiple rows the aggregation can only only give 1 value and in this case the first value. The last value you can probably get by adding a MAX aggregation on those columns.

Comment: select a.job_number, b.employee_end, b.qty_comp, b.`date`, a.job_scrap, a.job_time from (     select jobs.job_number, SUM(jobs.scrap) as job_scrap, SUM(jobs.job_time) as job_time          FROM jobs where jobs.job_number in (              SELECT j.job_number FROM jobs j                  WHERE j.moved_to = 'shipped'                    AND j.date BETWEEN %s AND %s  AND j.qty_comp > 0            )      GROUP BY jobs.job_number ) as a, jobs b where a.job_number = b.job_number   and b.moved_to = 'shipped'   and b.date between %s AND %s   and b.qty_comp > 0 group by b.job_number

Comment: would appreciate it if you could upvote or accept the answer. Thanks.